# WooCommerce reverse behavior of Ship to different address checkbox?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to reverse the behavior of "Ship to a different address" checkbox on checkout page. When its checked, Shipping form goes hide and Billing form takes the information. I found and changed this line in checkout.js

```
$( 'div.shipping_address' ).hide();
if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
    $( 'div.shipping_address' ).slideDown();
}
```

to

```
$( 'div.shipping_address' ).slideDown();
if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
    $( 'div.shipping_address' ).hide();
}
```

it works fine (display as reverse) but when we place order the shipping-form data also updating. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will prevent updating shipping-form data during place an order

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woo_optional_fields');
    function woo_optional_fields($wcCheckout_fields) {
        if(//check your shipping condition here){       
            //unset your shipping fields manually here..!!!
            unset($wcCheckout_fields['shipping']['your_all_shipping_fields']);
        }
    }
```